# Cannot figure out "Unexpected token" in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I cannot figure out what the error means on line 42:18 Could someone explain, please.

**Error Message:**

> Line 42:18:  Parsing error: Unexpected token

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className="FlexContainer NavbarContainer">
            <ul className="NavBar">
                <div className="mobilecontainer LeftNav">
                    <h2 className="BrandName LeftNav mobileboxmenu inline">Kommonplaces</h2>
                    <div className="hamburger inline" onClick={this.showDropdownMenu}><img alt="menubtn" src={hamburger}></img></div>
                    { this.state.displayMenu ? (
                </div> This line is 42 

                <Dropdown/>

                <li className="RightNav"><Link to="/">Host Your Space</Link></li>
                <li className="RightNav"><Link to="/">About Us</Link></li>
                <li className="RightNav FarRight"><Link to="/">Contact Us</Link></li>

                <li className="RightNav"><Link to="/">Sign Up</Link></li>
                <li className="RightNav"><Link to="/">Login</Link></li>
            </ul>
                ):
            (
          null
            )
        }
       </div>

    );
  }
}

export default MobileDropdown;
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. `<div>` cannot be a child element of `<ul>`. Only `<li>` can.

Comment: @Quentin How do I fixed it to not my a child element?

Comment: Probably by moving it outside of the `<ul>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should be:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="FlexContainer NavbarContainer">
        <ul className="NavBar">
          <div className="mobilecontainer LeftNav">
            <h2 className="BrandName LeftNav mobileboxmenu inline">
              Kommonplaces
            </h2>
            <div className="hamburger inline" onClick={this.showDropdownMenu}>
              <img alt="menubtn" src={hamburger} />
            </div>
            {this.state.displayMenu ? (
              <>
                <Dropdown />

                <li className="RightNav">
                  <Link to="/">Host Your Space</Link>
                </li>
                <li className="RightNav">
                  <Link to="/">About Us</Link>
                </li>
                <li className="RightNav FarRight">
                  <Link to="/">Contact Us</Link>
                </li>

                <li className="RightNav">
                  <Link to="/">Sign Up</Link>
                </li>
                <li className="RightNav">
                  <Link to="/">Login</Link>
                </li>
              </>
            ) : null}
          </div>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

JSX is not *strings* of HTML that get mashed together and passed to the browser's HTML parser for converting to a DOM. It is syntax for creating *elements* in JavaScript.

You are trying to start a block of JSX with `</div>` which is an *end* tag. You need a matching *start* tag first.

Comment: My questions are so I have a matching starting tag

Comment: @bpdg — No, you don't. `</div>` is the **very first thing** in the JSX section that is the first value after the ternary operator